# Monitoring and reducing High CPU usage percentage

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, production-environment, webmin

Good Morning.
Currently I am running a Java web application in Ubuntu server 11.10. For my Java application, I am using apache, tomcat and mysql.

For past few weeks, the CPU usage percentage of my production server is very high. It almost reaches to the maximum level of 100%.

I confirmed through my Amazon Web Console that, my CPU percentage is keep on increasing and decreasing. I have also checked through webmin (installed in my Ubuntu server) and confirmed that **CPU usage has 100% user**.

I have installed Java melody to monitor my Java application and found that there was no issues with Java or tomcat memory.

Can anyone please suggest me the reason for such high CPU usage percentage and the solutions to monitor and minimize them (or keep in control).

Thank You.

Comment: Have you found any pattern to when the CPU increases? Is it when a user logs in, when an admin goes to the admin panel, when I post a topic, when I send an email, anything like that?

Comment: Sorry. I tried to view the pattern, but I wasn't able to find successfully. But I think, its not from my application side (not sure), as the CPU percentage high is not occurring during a particular action. It keeps on increasing and suddenly decreases after a particular time. Also can you please give me some suggestion to find the process which is consuming such high CPU. Thanks again for your quick reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have used this before to try to track down resource usage:

http://webminstats.sourceforge.net/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/webminstats/

it will possible give you better insight into your troubles